# Loading Plotly line graphs

Tags: javascript, html, plotly.js

I am using plotly js offline line graphs in HTML, when the json has more data its taking more than one min to load.
We have left nav bar , when switching from one tab to another its taking more time to load the content due to plotly line graphs.

Data for line graph:   X-axis having 15 transactions, each transaction has around 5000 points to plot.
Approaches I have tried:

1. Giving an event listener for HTML on load of the page , minified the files (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Author_fast-loading_HTML_pages).
2. Giving “type: scatterGL” for line graphs and plotly.react(id,data,layout) instead of plotly.newPlot(id,data,layout).
   By using above approaches also its taking same time.

May I please kindly know if anyone know  how the loading time can be reduced for large data.

Thanks,
Bhuvana.

Answer (score 0):

That is a lot of points. 75,000 points means that Plotly is adding DOM elements. That is way too many for any library. Consider using Canvas instead, Plotly has support for it and [this example](https://plotly.com/javascript/pointcloud/#advanced-point-cloud) shows how it can handle 1 million points in a scatter plot, no problem.